# When new image is created, image.width returns 0

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

The code below says that `spike.image.width = 0`. Why is this? I'm probably missing something that is obvious.

```js
class Spike {
  constructor(x = 200, y = 200) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIBO-v6hQoEBhzmZ05mKzgYqrsZ0svgsED7IDR4dIVNxc78uc2";
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
const spike = new Spike;
console.log(spike.image.width);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="600"></canvas>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `console.log` fires, the image hasn't fully loaded yet. You have to check for when the image has loaded

```
const spike = new Spike;
spike.image.onload = function()
{
    console.log(spike.image.width);
}
```